# How to get the max value of the scrollbar NOT the scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

Is there javascript that grabs the max value of a scrollbar? If I use
`element.getBoundingClientRect().left`
it returns a value of 0 until the page is scrolled. I don't need the scrollbar position and I don't want to use an eventListener or setTimeout function to get this value. Any suggestions?